# Angular Typerror

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I keep getting the error below in my code where I am trying to display a newly edited and saved text after refreshing the page. I initialized the variable, made the access variable public but nothing worked. What am I missing here?

HTML:

```
<p>
                <span contenteditable [textContent]="_stickerData?.StickerData" (input)="onStickerDataChange($event.target.innerHTML)">
                    {{_stickerData?.StickerData}}
                </span>
            </p>          
        </div>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
            <button mat-button matRipple class="purple-500 fuse-white-fg mr-12" (click)="save()"> Etiket Güncelle </button>
        </div>
```

TS:

```
public_stickerData: IStickerData = {};
Filter: IFilter = {};

@Input()
  set StickerData(prm: IStickerData) {
      if (this._stickerData != prm) {
          this._stickerData = prm;
      }
  }
  get StickerData(): IStickerData {
      return this._stickerData;
  }

 ngOnInit() {
    this._productionService.getStickerDataList(this.Filter)
    .subscribe((response: any) => this._stickerData.StickerData = response);
    
  }


 onStickerDataChange(data) {
    this._stickerData.StickerData = data;
}
save(){
    this.confirmDialogRef = this._dialog.open(FuseConfirmDialogComponent, {
        disableClose: false,
    });
    
    this.confirmDialogRef.componentInstance.confirmMessage =
    "Etiket bilgileri değiştirilecektir, emin misiniz?";

this.confirmDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
    if (result) {
        this._productionService
            .saveStickerData(this._stickerData)
            .subscribe((response: IStickerData) => {
                this._stickerData = response;
                this._messages.Show(
                    "Etiket güncellendi",
                    "BAŞARILI",
                    3
    

        );
            this.cd.markForCheck();
        });
}
});

}
```

Service TS:

```
getStickerDataList(data: IFilter): Observable<IStickerData[]> {
        return this._http.post("Production/GetStickerDataList", data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to access one more deep level of the object, It is available by default as private instance.
`this` Itself represent the class instance. You can directly access `this._stickerData`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._productionService.getStickerDataList(this.Filter)
    .subscribe((response: any) => this._stickerData = response); // no need to use this._stickerData.StickerData
  }
```

Also make sure you are getting the data in the return.

Comment: The error is gone now thank you, but the edited text disappears after I refresh the page like I didn't do anything to it. Should I add something more?

Comment: When you refresh the page, all local data and variables re initialize and it fetch by default same data from the URL, I guess. Can you create a stackblitz or share more code html, it not sure what you wanted to do ? Any data you edit on page after refresh it will gone until you save it in any storage, like a db or localstorage depend on use case.

Comment: I shared my HTML and also the save operation. I don't know why when I refresh the page the saved data is gone...

Comment: When you save, the data is suppose to save in the DB with API call, so next time on page refresh you call the API you get the latest data. If you can debug check every time you will be getting the same data in API, that means save is not working properly, API call is perfect but check things on server side.